# wp sanitize_callback and static method

Tags: php, wordpress

this works:

```
function sanitize_select( $input, $setting ) {
    $input = sanitize_key( $input );
    $choices = $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id )->choices;
    return ( array_key_exists( $input, $choices ) ? $input : $setting->default );
}

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'layout', array(
    'default'           => 'one-column',
    'type'              => 'theme_mod',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport'         => 'postMessage',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_select',
) );
```

but, is it possible to convert **sanitize_select** function to static method and call it from **sanitize_callback**? passing **$input** and **$setting** vars is where i'm stuck.